# Any JEE OIDC agents for jee servers jboss & wildfly?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, jboss7.x, openid-connect

We are extending our authentication/autorization web security models to include OIDC. We would like to integrate our jboss7+ servers to the existing entrerprise IAM based on NetIQ products.
Redhat provides PEP (policy enforcement point) agents for jboss wildfly that support OIDC but only for their own IdP (autorization provider) which is keycloak (or Redhat SSO). We are not very confortable in adapting the keycloak agents code in order to support our IdP neither do we want to deploy Keycloak as a broker between our apps and our IdP (as redhat is sugggesting to us).
While there is a large number of java frameworks and libraries that support OIDC/Oauth2, we didn't find any PEP ready to use in a JEE container (using JASPIC for example). To closest we found is pac4j but it's implemented as a servlet filter and it doesn't integrate with the standard JEE security API (Subject, Principal...).
Is anyone aware of a possible implementation independent of the IdP ?